# HTML / CSS / Javascript editor for the iPad?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, applications, ios, html

I'm interested for a code editor for my iPad.

I've made a search on Apple Store for "HTML", and I've got a huge amount of results..

Can anyone recommend any of them?

It would be nice to have syntax-highlighting, to be able to open many files simultaneously (tabs?) and a nifty way to import, export files. Dropbox would be perfect!

Comment: Any free ones Because i am 11 and I don't have a visa card

Comment: @Karinader [Edhita](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/edhita-open-source-text-editor/id398896655?mt=8), [Jsany](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/javascript-anywhere/id363452277?mt=8), [VIM](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vim/id492668168?mt=8), [Codeanywhere](https://itunes.apple.com/hr/app/codeanywhere/id436736239?mt=8)..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the best one out there is called [**Textastic**](http://www.textasticapp.com/). It supports FTP, DropBox and WebDav and has a keyboard geared for editing code. It also has syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 4):

There is also [Diet Coda](http://panic.com/dietcoda/) from Panic, designed as a companion for Coda but it can certainly be used independently.

Unfortunately, it lacks support for Dropbox syncing. iCloud syncing exists if you use the App Store version of Coda.

Answer (score 4):

You might also try Kodiak JavaScript: http://www.becomekodiak.com/kodiak-javascript.html. It has syntax highlighting, tabs and keyboard extensions.

Note that I am a co-author of this app, but I hope it is okay to advertise it here, because it seems to be related to the question asked.

Comment: No longer available.

Answer (score 3):

+1 for Textastic, which is my fave as well. But [Gusto](http://horseandtherook.com/gusto/) deserves a mention as the other top code editor for iPad.

You can't go too far wrong either way. I ultimately preferred Textastic because it is less web-oriented and more of a general programmer's editor. It supports more languages out of the box, allows custom roll-your-own syntax highlighting definitions, and has a really usable cursor navigation scheme.

But meanwhile, Gusto has one big killer feature for the web developers: a built-in browser for remote previewing/testing after you upload your code to the server. Textastic can do local preview of HTML and Markdown, but that's really no substitute for seeing your work in place on the server. Granted, you can multitask on over to Safari from Textastic, but Gusto just makes round-tripping your web code that wee bit easier.

Long story short...if you're mostly a web dev (which I'm not), Gusto deserves a look.