# Is there any IDE for iPad?

Tags: ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML / CSS / Javascript editor for the iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11719/html-css-javascript-editor-for-the-ipad)

Is there any IDE like Notepad++ for iPad? I want to create HTML pages with CSS and jQuery on my iPad.

Comment: It would be interesting to wider the question to the iPhone & iPod Touch.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used it myself, but Textastic ($10) should help you with a lot of what you're looking to do.

http://www.textasticapp.com/